# What can I do with C++ modules in Visual Studio 2015 so far? (using the experimental switch)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

So I was looking at a [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2015/805) showing the news in 'Visual Studio 2015 Update 1' and they mentioned experimental C++ module support (about 8 minutes in).

How much of this feature is actually supported in this version?

I would love if someone would show some kind of code example that works with the Visual Studio /experimental switch, so that I can start playing around with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to get a simple example working with the Update 1 RTM, based on the instructions in the video linked in @dxiv's answer.

First, the module definition file `mine.ixx`. Compile it with: `cl /c /experimental:module mine.ixx`. This will make `mine.obj` and `mine.ifc`:

```
module mine;
export
{
  int sum(int x, int y);
}

int sum(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
```

Next `main.cpp` that uses the module, compile with `cl /c /experimental:module main.cpp`. This will make `main.obj`:

```
#include <iostream>
import mine;

int main()
{
  std::cout << sum(2000, 15) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then link these with `link *.obj`, and you should get a `main.exe`.

Note that this doesn't work very well from inside VS at the moment since it doesn't understand the ordering requirements that the modules impose - you'd have to manually modify your project files to do this.

Comment: I like this answer. One thing though, I couldn't use this solution right off the bat. I had to add the /MD switch in the second compiler step to avoid linker errors later on. Not sure if we have different setups (I simply ran everything from my Visual Studio binary folder) but I thought I should mention it if someone else gets the same problem.

Comment: With VS we can create a module def file but its extension is def not ixx.

Comment: @lasithc: that's a different meaning of "module definition file" :)

Comment: ahh ok, I have a requirement to use this newly introduced module feature inside VS 2015. Where I have cpp and .h files in my VS project. But my VS project is not a typical C++ project. So Intellisense is not working. So with this new feature is there a possibility to get Intellisense support inside VS for cpp files those are not in a cpp project. (I was thinking about importing .h files with this feature and get available methods of them in Intellisense menu).

Comment: In the command line to compile main.cpp to main.obj, how does the compiler know where to find mine.ifc. Does the compiler look in the current directory by default ? Or in the same directory as the source file being compiled ? I think it would be a better answer if this was specified explicitly.
Edit : According to another answer below, this should be  -module:reference mine.ifc

Comment: @JohanBoule it looks in the current directory and then any other directories specified by `/module:search`

Comment: @Porges Is "-module:reference mine.ifc" necessary, or does the "import mine;" statement suffice ?

Answer (score 7):

See the CppCon 2015 presentation of Gabriel Dos Reis “*Large Scale C++ with Modules: What You Should Know*" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwdQA0pGWa4.

From http://nibblestew.blogspot.com/2015/10/some-comments-on-c-modules-talk.html:

> The way modules are used (at around 40 minutes in the presentation) has a nasty quirk. The basic approach is that you have a source file foo.cpp, which defines a module Foobar. To compile this you should say this:
>
> cl -c /module foo.cxx
>
> The causes the compiler to output foo.o as well as Foobar.ifc, which contains the binary definition of the module. To use this you would compile a second source file like this:
>
> cl -c baz.cpp /module:reference Foobar.ifc
>
> This is basically the same way that Fortran does its modules [...]

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Thank you for the update. Things move fast nowadays, especially with "experimental" features.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2015 Update 1 RTM, use `/experimental:module /module:import` instead.

Comment: That should be `/module:reference`, `/module:import` gives an error