# Placement and overview of VS2015 U3 experimental switches

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2015, c++17

I found `/experimental:modules` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34016681/3434465) and apparently it is passed to cl.exe in command line mode.

`/std:c++latest` is mentioned [there](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs).

Searching in VS2015U3 files for `clamp` (`std::clamp`, not default-enabled) yields the macro `_HAS_CXX17`, which has to be defined as `1` to enable the function.

`std::filesystem` is available in a nested namespace as `std::experimental::filesystem` without conditional macros.

I wish for as complete C++17 (including TS) support as is currently available.

- **Where is a list of all the switches and/or macros necessary?**
- **In the IDE, where do I put these switches?**
- **Do I have to define the macros as well?**

My Google Fu has failed me. Answer may be as simple as linking to the appropriate manual page... should that exist.

Comment: Looks like there is no IDE property page for new /std switches yet. I just add it into C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options.

Comment: @RyhorSpivak : Did that as well. Had no effect on the library though - figures. I am somewhat loathe to just start defining macros left and right to get what I want - surely there must be an "intended way" to do it?